# Can gradient descent be written without time step?

Tags: optimization

I am trying to learn gradient descent for machine learning. In this highly cited research paper https://arxiv.org/pdf/1609.04747.pdf, the author presents the gradient descent as

$$\theta  = \theta - \eta \nabla_\theta J(\theta)$$

I have never seen this expression before. Is this some analytical formula for calculating the variables $\theta$? Wouldn't the $\theta$ be cancelled out? I am confused, please help.

Comment: The $\theta$ is actually reiterative. So it should be $\theta_{k+1} = \theta_k - \eta\nabla_\theta J(\theta)$.  And perhaps the $\eta$ should be subscripted too.  Thats why the thetas dont cancel out.

Comment: Now Im not entirely sure where this particular expression came from.  I do know the gradient descent method, though. Ive studied it in a convex optimization course. It involves a step size, and Im presuming that is what $\eta$ is, and it involves a step direction, which Im presuming is what $\nabla_\theta J(\theta)$ is, though Im unfamiliar with the notation.  Does $J$ refer to the Jacobian or some other matrix?  There are slight modifications to the gradient descent method that involves another matrix to improve efficiency.

Answer (score 0):

As @CogitoErgoCogitoSum mentioned in the comments, the iteration should be written as
$$
\theta^{k+1} = \theta^k - \eta \nabla J(\theta^k).
$$
Starting at the point $\theta^k$, we take a step in the direction of steepest descent (that is, the negative gradient direction), which moves us to a new point $\theta^{k+1}$ where the value of $J$ has been reduced.